# Only allow multiples of 10s from the user

Tags: c#

I was wondering how to only allow users to input values that are multiples of 10 i.e. 10, 20, 30 and so on. Example of a number that's not allowed 105.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply reject values that are not multiples of 10

Comment: Use [% Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)

Comment: I doubt that you are treating your users right.

Comment: @TaW What do you mean?

Comment: Well, I don't know any details, but what do you do with the rejected values? Force the users to 'correct' them? Autocorrect the input and surprise the users? This is the kind of error that shouldn't be possible in the first place. Can't tell you though what would be best. NumericUpDowns or TrackBars would prevent the problem but they are so ugly..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [% Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)

```
if(userInput % 10 == 0)
{
    //valid
}
```

Comment: I'll accept the answer when it allows me to, thank you very much :)!

Comment: No worries :) In short, it basically retrieves the remainder from a division by 10

Comment: Also there is the NumericUpDown control, which you can set Increment 10, ReadOnly to prevent typing, BackColor back to Window so it does not look disabled when ReadOnly is set.